# Waiting for closed cmd in c#,asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, wait

I am running cmd on background via asp.net. I want to wait program, until closed cmd window ?
How can I succeed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to Emre Acar's answer, if you start the `cmd` yourself with `Process.Start()` you can probably do this:

```
var process = Process.Start(@"c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe");
process.WaitForExit();
```

instead of cycling through all the open processes. Since you mention `asp.net`, if you're starting the process in the page, you may have a lot of consoles running at the same time (one per page) and each page would want to wait for only the one it opened to complete.

Also take a look at the docs for WaitForExit. There are other overloads and [you may want to specify a timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56.aspx) (so that your page does not get stuck waiting for a long time...)

Comment: Its working this code. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 1):

i think this will work.

```
foreach(Process cmdprocess in Process.GetProcessesByName("cmd"))
{
cmdprocess.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: object would be var or Process in foreach loop

Comment: Use `var cmdprocess` instead of `object cmdprocess`

Comment: I tried and it doesnt work for me.